# How to read a formated chain until a certain point in C?

Tags: c, string, file, fseek

I am currently struggling with file manipulations in C and still have a lot of reflexes to acquire.
My code is here :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* f = fopen("/Users/[...].txt","r+");
    int input1=0; int input2=0; int input3=0;
    
    fscanf(f,"sommets : %d\n",&input1);
    printf("%d\n",input1);
    fscanf(f,"transitions : %d\n",&input1);
    printf("%d\n",input1);
    printf("%ld\n",ftell(f));
    fscanf(f,"ARCS PRE\n");
    printf("%ld\n",ftell(f));
    long int point = ftell(f);
    char word[10]="ARCS POST"; char data[100];
    while((strcmp(word, fgets(data,100,f)))!=0){ 
        fseek(f,point-ftell(f), (int) ftell(f));  //to reposition the cursor after strcmp
        fscanf(f, "%d->%d,%d\n", &input1, &input2, &input3);
        printf("%d->%d,%d\n",input1, input2, input3);
        point =ftell(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The part which is not working is around the while : here is the file I try to read

```
sommets : 69
transitions : 9
ARCS PRE
1->2,5
1->3,7
ARCS POST
1->7,1
1->9,4
END
```

The while is supposed to stop the reading once I reach "ARCS POST" in the file but never recognizes such a string, and it seems that the fseek in the loop doesn't want to work. In fact I also tried with SEEK_CUR but its value seems stuck to 1. Does anyone have an alternative for what I am trying to do ? Or does anyone know why nothing goes on this part as intended ?

Comment: `while((strcmp(word, fgets(data,100,f)))!=0){` What do you expect to happen if you the reach end of the file?

Comment: `fseek(f,point-ftell(f), (int) ftell(f));` What is this supposed to do? Did you read manual for `fseek`? How do your arguments match expected parameters?

Comment: In fact the while loop is here an infinite loop, I set a counter to 5, and if the file is not finished at the end of the counter it ends the while. I just removedit  for more comprehension.

Comment: Where did you get the idea for this weird mix of `fgets`, `fseek` and `fscanf`? That looks terrible. Why don't you just read the line with `fgets` and check the content with `sscanf`? And why don't you check return value of `fscanf`? You should do this for all IO functions. Did you check what happends in `fscanf` when you read a line that does not match the `%d->%d,%d` pattern?

Comment: For the line including fseek, its purpose is to reposition the cursor in the file where it was previously before the execution on strcmp in the while loop. The arguments have the right type, but it seems to never excecutes as the return value of fseek is always different of 0.

Comment: "I also tried with SEEK_CUR" Maybe you should show that version. But in general, it seems that you want to do `fseek(f,point,SEEK_SET)`.  Also keep in mind, that for text files you might need to use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` according to [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html): " On some non-UNIX systems, an fpos_t object may be a complex object and these routines may be the only way to portably reposition a text stream."

Comment: Concerning the SEEK_cur verssion, i just removed the line with fseek by ```fseek(f,point-SEEK_CUR,SEEK_CUR)```

Comment: Didn't know about ```fgetpos```, and I honestly don't really understand the declaration of the type fpos_t. However I still don't know how to stop the reading of my file when ARCS POST is encountered... Is there any manipulation in C that could do the trick?

Comment: You generally shouldn't mix `fgets` and `fscanf` for reading files. In your case, you must also be aware that `fgets` will store the `\n` in the buffer. You must either remove from the input or add to your search string.